# Fix x-axis scale seaborn factorplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm attempting to make a figure that shows two plots, with each plot separated based on a set of categorical data. However, although I can make the graph, I cant figure out how to get the x-axis to be properly spaced.

I want the x-axis to start before the first value (want axis to start at 60 [first value = 63]) and end after the last (want axis to end at 95 [last value = 92.1]), with xticks going up in 5's.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.axes
import seaborn as sns

Temperature = [63.0,63.3,63.6,63.9,64.2,64.5,64.8,65.2,65.5,65.8,66.1,66.4,66.7,67.0,67.3,67.7,68.0,68.3,68.6,68.9,69.2,69.5,69.9,70.2,70.5,70.8,71.1,71.4,71.8,72.1,72.4,72.7,73.0,73.4,73.7,74.0,74.3,74.6,74.9,75.2,75.6,75.9,76.2,76.5,76.9,77.2,77.5,77.8,78.1,78.5,78.8,79.1,79.4,79.7,80.1,80.4,80.7,81.0,81.3,81.6,81.9,82.3,82.6,82.9,83.2,83.5,83.8,84.1,84.4,84.8,85.1,85.4,85.7,86.0,86.3,86.6,86.9,87.2,87.5,87.8,88.1,88.4,88.7,89.0,89.3,89.6,89.8,90.1,90.4,90.7,91.0,91.2,91.5,91.8,92.1,63.0,63.3,63.6,63.9,64.2,64.5,64.8,65.2,65.5,65.8,66.1,66.4,66.7,67.0,67.3,67.7,68.0,68.3,68.6,68.9,69.2,69.5,69.9,70.2,70.5,70.8,71.1,71.4,71.8,72.1,72.4,72.7,73.0,73.4,73.7,74.0,74.3,74.6,74.9,75.2,75.6,75.9,76.2,76.5,76.9,77.2,77.5,77.8,78.1,78.5,78.8,79.1,79.4,79.7,80.1,80.4,80.7,81.0,81.3,81.6,81.9,82.3,82.6,82.9,83.2,83.5,83.8,84.1,84.4,84.8,85.1,85.4,85.7,86.0,86.3,86.6,86.9,87.2,87.5,87.8,88.1,88.4,88.7,89.0,89.3,89.6,89.8,90.1,90.4,90.7,91.0,91.2,91.5,91.8,92.1]

Derivative = [0.0495,0.0507,0.0525,0.0548,0.0570,0.0579,0.0579,0.0574,0.0574,0.0576,0.0581,0.0587,0.0593,0.0592,0.0584,0.0580,0.0579,0.0580,0.0582,0.0588,0.0592,0.0594,0.0588,0.0581,0.0578,0.0579,0.0580,0.0579,0.0582,0.0581,0.0579,0.0574,0.0571,0.0563,0.0548,0.0538,0.0536,0.0540,0.0544,0.0551,0.0556,0.0551,0.0542,0.0535,0.0536,0.0542,0.0564,0.0623,0.0748,0.0982,0.1360,0.1897,0.2550,0.3228,0.3807,0.4177,0.4248,0.3966,0.3365,0.2558,0.1713,0.0971,0.0438,0.0140,0.0034,0.0028,0.0048,0.0058,0.0057,0.0050,0.0042,0.0038,0.0039,0.0041,0.0038,0.0031,0.0023,0.0017,0.0014,0.0012,0.0015,0.0019,0.0020,0.0018,0.0017,0.0015,0.0014,0.0014,0.0015,0.0014,0.0013,0.0011,0.0007,0.0004,0.0011,0.0105,0.0100,0.0096,0.0090,0.0084,0.0081,0.0077,0.0071,0.0066,0.0063,0.0064,0.0060,0.0057,0.0055,0.0054,0.0051,0.0047,0.0046,0.0042,0.0037,0.0035,0.0040,0.0043,0.0039,0.0032,0.0028,0.0028,0.0027,0.0029,0.0034,0.0038,0.0034,0.0027,0.0024,0.0021,0.0017,0.0015,0.0016,0.0015,0.0011,0.0008,0.0012,0.0019,0.0025,0.0027,0.0026,0.0019,0.0012,0.0010,0.0014,0.0016,0.0014,0.0010,0.0007,0.0007,0.0010,0.0017,0.0021,0.0020,0.0013,0.0012,0.0013,0.0014,0.0015,0.0018,0.0017,0.0012,0.0013,0.0018,0.0028,0.0031,0.0033,0.0027,0.0022,0.0015,0.0016,0.0022,0.0026,0.0026,0.0019,0.0012,0.0006,0.0007,0.0011,0.0016,0.0014,0.0010,0.0009,0.0012,0.0015,0.0014,0.0008,0.0001,-0.0003,0.0002]

Category = ["a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b"]

df = pd.DataFrame({"Temperature": Temperature,
    "Derivative": Derivative, 
    "Category" : Category})

g = sns.factorplot(x="Temperature", y="Derivative", data=df, col="Category")
g.set_xticklabels(step=10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the desired feature you describe suggest that using a `factorplot` here is absolutely the wrong choice. Instead use a normal matplotlib plot and then set the limits as usual, `plt.xlim(60,95)`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Temperature = [63.0,63.3,63.6,63.9,64.2,64.5,64.8,65.2,65.5,65.8,66.1,66.4,66.7,67.0,67.3,67.7,68.0,68.3,68.6,68.9,69.2,69.5,69.9,70.2,70.5,70.8,71.1,71.4,71.8,72.1,72.4,72.7,73.0,73.4,73.7,74.0,74.3,74.6,74.9,75.2,75.6,75.9,76.2,76.5,76.9,77.2,77.5,77.8,78.1,78.5,78.8,79.1,79.4,79.7,80.1,80.4,80.7,81.0,81.3,81.6,81.9,82.3,82.6,82.9,83.2,83.5,83.8,84.1,84.4,84.8,85.1,85.4,85.7,86.0,86.3,86.6,86.9,87.2,87.5,87.8,88.1,88.4,88.7,89.0,89.3,89.6,89.8,90.1,90.4,90.7,91.0,91.2,91.5,91.8,92.1,63.0,63.3,63.6,63.9,64.2,64.5,64.8,65.2,65.5,65.8,66.1,66.4,66.7,67.0,67.3,67.7,68.0,68.3,68.6,68.9,69.2,69.5,69.9,70.2,70.5,70.8,71.1,71.4,71.8,72.1,72.4,72.7,73.0,73.4,73.7,74.0,74.3,74.6,74.9,75.2,75.6,75.9,76.2,76.5,76.9,77.2,77.5,77.8,78.1,78.5,78.8,79.1,79.4,79.7,80.1,80.4,80.7,81.0,81.3,81.6,81.9,82.3,82.6,82.9,83.2,83.5,83.8,84.1,84.4,84.8,85.1,85.4,85.7,86.0,86.3,86.6,86.9,87.2,87.5,87.8,88.1,88.4,88.7,89.0,89.3,89.6,89.8,90.1,90.4,90.7,91.0,91.2,91.5,91.8,92.1]

Derivative = [0.0495,0.0507,0.0525,0.0548,0.0570,0.0579,0.0579,0.0574,0.0574,0.0576,0.0581,0.0587,0.0593,0.0592,0.0584,0.0580,0.0579,0.0580,0.0582,0.0588,0.0592,0.0594,0.0588,0.0581,0.0578,0.0579,0.0580,0.0579,0.0582,0.0581,0.0579,0.0574,0.0571,0.0563,0.0548,0.0538,0.0536,0.0540,0.0544,0.0551,0.0556,0.0551,0.0542,0.0535,0.0536,0.0542,0.0564,0.0623,0.0748,0.0982,0.1360,0.1897,0.2550,0.3228,0.3807,0.4177,0.4248,0.3966,0.3365,0.2558,0.1713,0.0971,0.0438,0.0140,0.0034,0.0028,0.0048,0.0058,0.0057,0.0050,0.0042,0.0038,0.0039,0.0041,0.0038,0.0031,0.0023,0.0017,0.0014,0.0012,0.0015,0.0019,0.0020,0.0018,0.0017,0.0015,0.0014,0.0014,0.0015,0.0014,0.0013,0.0011,0.0007,0.0004,0.0011,0.0105,0.0100,0.0096,0.0090,0.0084,0.0081,0.0077,0.0071,0.0066,0.0063,0.0064,0.0060,0.0057,0.0055,0.0054,0.0051,0.0047,0.0046,0.0042,0.0037,0.0035,0.0040,0.0043,0.0039,0.0032,0.0028,0.0028,0.0027,0.0029,0.0034,0.0038,0.0034,0.0027,0.0024,0.0021,0.0017,0.0015,0.0016,0.0015,0.0011,0.0008,0.0012,0.0019,0.0025,0.0027,0.0026,0.0019,0.0012,0.0010,0.0014,0.0016,0.0014,0.0010,0.0007,0.0007,0.0010,0.0017,0.0021,0.0020,0.0013,0.0012,0.0013,0.0014,0.0015,0.0018,0.0017,0.0012,0.0013,0.0018,0.0028,0.0031,0.0033,0.0027,0.0022,0.0015,0.0016,0.0022,0.0026,0.0026,0.0019,0.0012,0.0006,0.0007,0.0011,0.0016,0.0014,0.0010,0.0009,0.0012,0.0015,0.0014,0.0008,0.0001,-0.0003,0.0002]

Category = ["a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b"]

df = pd.DataFrame({"Temperature": Temperature,
    "Derivative": Derivative, 
    "Category" : Category})

for n, data in df.groupby("Category"):
    plt.plot(data["Temperature"],data["Derivative"] , marker="o", label=n)

plt.xlim(60,95)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or if subplots are desired,

```
fig,axes = plt.subplots(ncols=len(df["Category"].unique()), sharey=True)
for ax,(n, data) in zip(axes,df.groupby("Category")):
    ax.plot(data["Temperature"],data["Derivative"] , marker="o", label=n)
    ax.set_title("Category {}".format(n))
    ax.set_xlim(60,95)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Finally, you may use a seaborn FacetGrid onto which you plot your data with a `plot`:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="Category")
g.map(plt.plot, "Temperature", "Derivative",marker="o",)

for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.set_xlim(60,95)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yup that completely sorted it. Awesome! Thanks again!